# How to apply previous row result in pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to understand how to go around this in python pandas. My objective is to fill column "RESULT" with the initial investment and apply the profit on top of the previous result.

So if I would use an excel spreadsheet I would do this:

1. Ask what's the initial_investment (in this example $350)
2. Compute the first row as profit/100*initial_investment + initial_investment
3. the 2nd and forth will be the same with the exception that "initial_investment" is in the raw above.

[image]

my initial python code is this

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"DATE":[2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016],"PROFIT":[10,4,5,7,-10,5,-5,3],"RESULT":[350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350]})
print df
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the cumulative product function [`cumprod()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumprod.html):

```
df['RESULT'] = ((df.PROFIT + 100) / 100.).cumprod() * 350
```

First you transform `df.PROFIT` into a proportion of the previous value.  Then `cumprod()` multiplies each row by the previous rows.  You can then just multiply this by whatever your initial value is.

Comment: No problem!  I can see why it was a little puzzling - I first thought the answer should use `shift()` in some way.  Thanks for stating the problem clearly and putting the desired output and replication code in the question.

Comment: Yes, I tried to use shift but got nowhere. Usually when I get nowhere, I ask my best friend stackoverflow